# Limpar CEP com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, código-postal

Como limpar a formatação de um campo de CEP nesse formato: `87.678-000`?

Preciso tirar os "." e os "-" e retornar apenas os números.  Tentei algo do tipo, infelizmente não deu certo.

```
var i = '^[0-9]+$';
var reg = new RegExp(i);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Uma alternativa a solução apresentada pelo @Renan é utilizar essa expressão regular `/\.|\-/` para remover os caracteres `.` e `-` de uma string:

```
var cep = '87.678-000';
cep = cep.replace(/\.|\-/g, '');

alert(cep); // 87678000
```

Aonde o modificador [`/g`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_g.asp) é utilizado para procurar uma ou mais ocorrências em que `.` e `-` é encontrado, de uso global.

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/du2sd/)

---

Para verificar se um CEP é válido(*no formato fornecido por você*) poderia ser usado algo assim:

```
var cep = '87.678-000';
if (/\d{2}\.\d{3}\-\d{3}/.test(cep))
    alert('Cep é válido!');
else
    alert('Cep inválido!');
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7NVSX/)

Answer (score 16):

Se tudo que você quer é retirar os traços e pontos...

```
var str = str.replace("-", "").replace(".", "");
```

Onde `str` é a *string* com o CEP.

Se você quer ver se uma string é um CEP válido, pode usar algo do tipo:

```
// força bruta não, força brutíssima! // após 3 edições, já não tão bruta...
var regexp = /\d\d((\d\d\d)|(\.\d\d\d-))\d\d\d/;
var match = str.match(regexp);
```

Daí você verifica se houve match (se `match` for nulo, a string não é um CEP válido). Essa expressão regular vai pegar tanto CEP formatado quanto não formatado.

P.S.: estou a desconsiderar se CEP's com zeros a esquerdas são válidos, pois não conheço as regras de formação de CEP.

**Edição:** eu dei umas ajeitadas aí no código pra ele ficar menos bruto.

Comment: gostei do comentário: "força bruta não, força brutíssima!" kkkk +1 pela respota e pelo comentário

Comment: tou com o @TafarelChicotti, o comentário é qualquer coisa eheh

Comment: Deu certo amigo, obrigado!

Comment: Renan, aproveitando sua dica, tenho outro problema parecido. Tenho uma string assim: str = "000.000.000". Que são valores, como faço para substituir os dígitos, mais deixando os pontos "." ?

Comment: @user7605 Crie outra pergunta com essa dúvida. Assim mais gente irá ver, e você terá mais espaço para detalhar a pergunta ;)

Comment: Ok, estou criando

Answer (score 1):

Gostaria de complementar [a resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16860/limpar-cep-com-javascript/16863#16863) do @Renan com uma verdadeira validação de CEP.

Apesar de o CEP brasileiro não ser definido por um algoritmo propriamente dito e sim apenas uma [representação decimal estruturada do País](http://www.correios.com.br/para-voce/precisa-de-ajuda/o-que-e-cep-e-por-que-usa-lo/estrutura-do-cep), como qualquer estrutura lógica ela segue um padrão validável por Expressões Regulares.

Note que eu escrevi *Expressões Regulares*, no plural, pois temos 26 Estados + um Distrito Federal que, numa estrutura, resultam em 27 padrões diferentes.

Anos atrás, quando eu pesquisava por alternativas de preenchimento automático de informações com base num CEP, numa "época" em que não haviam muitos WebServices disponíveis e/ou confiáveis, eu acabei por encontrar a própria base de dados usada pelos Correios para download num blog que hoje já não existe mais.

O importante é que em meio aos comentários do artigo havia um de ninguém menos que [Aurélio Marinho Jargas](http://aurelio.net/), autor do melhor livro de referência para Expressões Regulares em português.

E nesse comentário em particular ele publicou essas 27 Expressões Regulares as quais eu tratei rapidamente de implementá-la em PHP. *Calma, cocada...*

Apesar da relativa dificuldade que eu tive em portar o código para JavaScript, eu o fiz, e deixo como referência para comunidade [no JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brunoaugusto/6fV6C/).

Após a verificação básica de comprimento, primeiro o Estado é checado por um Expressão Regular à parte. Só então testamos os cinco primeiros dígitos do CEP, que são os que importam contra a Expressão Regular do Estado informado.

Todo o crédito vai para o Mestre Aurélio, eu só empacotei tudo como um bom Padawan. ^_^

Comment: Note que você começa tirando da string todos os caracteres não numéricos (a chamada ao `replace`). Assim, `ab60125-asd1t50` seria um CEP válido. *Anyways* +1 por ser completo e preciso.

Comment: Agradeço pelo reconhecimento. Quanto ao ponto levantado, na verdade, 60125-150 é sim um CEP válido, mas lá em Fortaleza / CE. Por isso que a validação leva em conta também o Estado. Se essa string fosse dada como entrada para outro Estado, falharia.

Comment: O que quero dizer é que `60125-150` é um CEP válido, mas `aaaa6z\alfhkw012sljghwh5sadfslhfw-fwl1çskgnlhsghw5slkdf0` não é. Os números são os mesmos, mas as strings são diferentes. Eu garanto que um carteiro jogaria sua carta no lixo com um CEP como o segundo :D

Comment: Num cenário real, com certeza. Se uma correspondência fosse recebida pelos Correios com um CEP inválido, ela seria marcada com algo como "retornar ao remetente" ou "endereço insuficiente". Mas de todo jeito, essa filtragem entre correspondências bem e mal preenchidas é um tipo de validação. Não que os Correios tenham alguém pra ficar buscando números no meio de um texto pra adivinhar o destino, mas em todo caso...